# Change Year after update that Field in SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a problem with sql server,
in my DateCreated Field when i insert manually a date for example "**2017-04-13** 17:12:54.210" after Enter it change to "**2638-07-04** 17:12:54.210" data time !
could any body help me ?

the blow query is my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DayQuotations](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Speaker] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Sentence] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

[image]

---UPDATE

Where i use SQL Query To insert data it inserted correctly  :

```
  INSERT INTO DayQuotations (Speaker, Sentence, DateCreated)VALUES ('test2', 'test', '2017-04-13 17:51:07.563' );
```

So it has problem just with my manually insertion!!

Comment: no triggers on that table?

Comment: Do you use SSMS to enter this dates or is with any other desktop app?

Comment: @Mohammad, can you show your update query?

Comment: @Whencesoever no! that's a new Table !i  have not this problem but in this database today when i change every datetime field its year change to 2638!!

Comment: Why do you want to change a `DateCreated` field. You should default this field to `GetDate()` on insert.

Comment: @McNets i just Use MS SQL server Management studio and enter manually in edit table mode ! Just simple!

Comment: @WEI_DBA i know your way is curerct ! but in this case my manually insertion must insert datetime correctly in this field not by Change It!!

Comment: which are your regional settings?

Comment: Please run `dbcc useroptions` and copy&paste the result.

Comment: @McNets
 Set Option Value
textsize 2147483647
language us_english
dateformat mdy
datefirst 7
lock_timeout -1
quoted_identifier SET
arithabort SET
ansi_null_dflt_on SET
ansi_warnings SET
ansi_padding SET
ansi_nulls SET
concat_null_yields_null SET
isolation level read committed

Comment: Have you tried using SSMS Query Analyzer to enter the values through an `Insert ... Values()` command?

Comment: Please show the `UPDATE` query

Comment: please set dateformat to dmy

Comment: @McNets It was ! please check my previous answer !
 language --> us_english dateformat--> mdy datefirst--> 7 lock_timeout

Comment: I'm sorry but in your previous comment: `language us_english dateformat mdy ` <==

Comment: Oh ! Ok ! My bad ! i Try To change It!

Comment: @McNets i change SQL date-format to dmy as you say with SET DATEFORMAT dmy ; But the problem note resolved!

Comment: just another question is your server on anther computer?

Comment: No ! all of my work space is in my laptop !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Hijri calendar:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael/2007/04/29/sql-server-hijri-hijra-dates/

SQL Server interpret date you input as Hijri or something like this. Check you locale settings, I think problem with it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '7/05/2017 12:14:35:727PM', 131)
```

returns year 2578, not exactly yours, but close...

Comment: yes! but how i  change my sql server settings to solve this problem ?

Comment: Check Environment-international settings of managment studio, problem can be at client side too

Comment: I check updates from SSMS using profiler - dates are parsed by SSMS. It seems problems is on clients side.

Comment: i check it ! is was English !

Comment: i have to say that my region was Persia! but i change it to English regain and problem solved Now ! bu it is not right solution ! i must be in my region and sql server worked correctly !

Comment: You can change only date format in windows, but leave your region as Persia

Comment: i change windows calendar to gregurian with my main region (Persia) it worke fine ! but my calendare is not hijri right now

Comment: Please, mark my answer as accepted. You can also try another program to edit your data, maybe there are no such problems. (SQL Server and SSMS is diffrent software) https://www.vladan.fr/5-free-alternatives-microsoft-sql-management-studio/